# How to use promises to get an Observable?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have a class with an Observable in it. I want to create second Observable that will be generated by **the value of the first observable** and **the response of the HTTP-request**. I want to **regenerate value of the second Observalble** on every change in the first Observable.

I need to get `Observable<number> in returning type`. I tried to do it with `map`, `switchMap`, `fromPromise`. In some cases the returning type of the second Observable became `Observable<Observable<number>>` (when I used `map`), in some cases typescript hinted me that the returning type should be `ObservableInput<number>`.

Help me to understand how to correctly use promises in rxjs!

```
function someHTTPRequest(): Promise<number> {
}

class MyClass {
  firstObs$: Observable<Array<string>>;
  
  get secondObs$(): Observable<number> {
    return firstObs$.pipe(
     switchMap((items: Array<string>) => fromPromise(someHTTPRequest(items)))
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean pass the string items to the someHTTPrequest

```
function someHTTPRequest(items:Array<string>): Promise<number> {
}

class MyClass {
  firstObs$: Observable<Array<string>>;
  
  get secondObs$(): Observable<number> {
    return firstObs$.pipe(
     switchMap((items: Array<string>) => fromPromise(someHTTPRequest(items)))
    )
  }
}
```

when inside a mergeMap or switchmap you can return promises, so you do not need to use from.

```
class MyClass {
  firstObs$: Observable<Array<string>>;
  
  get secondObs$(): Observable<number> {
    return this.firstObs$.pipe(
     switchMap((items: Array<string>) => { 
         return someHTTPRequest(items));
    })
  }
}
```

EDIT:
based on the comment that the items array would be undifined is due to it starts the opservable with no values, you could turn it into a behavior subject and give it an initial value if that is not expected you could do this.

```
class MyClass {
  firstObs$: Observable<Array<string>>;
  
  get secondObs$(): Observable<number> {
    return this.firstObs$.pipe(
     switchMap((items: Array<string>) => { 
         if(items)
              return someHTTPRequest(items));
         return EMPTY;
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case it says:
Argument of type '(items: Array<string> | undefined) => Promise<number> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string[] | undefined, index: number) => ObservableInput<number>'.   Type 'Promise<number> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<number>'.     Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<number>

Comment: That would be an issue on the someHTTPRequest function having a loose end probably where it would not return a value under certain circumstances. You could turn the observable into a Observable<number|undifined> if you except those values, but that might cause you other issues if you use truthy and falsy values since undifined and 0 would be considered the same value.